# Request for ConfigurationPermission failed while attempting to access configuration section 'paypal'

Tags: paypal, web-config, integration

Hoping you will be doing good i am having some problem on my hosting server when i implement PayPal using Rest API Sample of Paypal and using Log4net

```
<section name="paypal" type="PayPal.Manager.SDKConfigHandler, PayPalCoreSDK" requirePermission="false"/>
        <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net" requirePermission="false"/>
```

All working fine on Local System but when i deploy it to my GoDaddy Server its not working. Currently i am using SandBox Credentials.

It is showing Error

```
"Request for ConfigurationPermission failed while attempting to access configuration section 'paypal'. To allow all callers to access the data for this section, set section attribute 'requirePermission' equal 'false' in the configuration file where this section is declared."
```

And sometime is is showing this error: `"Request Failed"`

Please help in this context.

Thanks,
Adeel